# VB to R: Is there an equivalent to Dim (x,y) in R?

Tags: r, vb.net

I'm migrating a small program from VB (an excel-embedded macro that I'm just reading with VB I guess) to R. Sorry if the question is stupid, but I haven't worked with VB before.

I have a set of `Dim` statements that I think are assigning vectors/matrices:

```
Dim ff(nmax) As Double
Dim jmatrix(nmax, kmax) As Double
```

I think this is how I would create it in R:

```
ff<-as.numeric(0:nmax)
jmatrix<-matrix(nrows=0:nmax,ncols=0:kmax)
```

But I think I would have to do this every time `jmatrix` (for example) was used in the code, and I have a suspicion that `nmax` and `kmax` are going to be changing or looping a lot. I can do that, but its really convenient how VB just declares them once at the start: can I do this in R? To phrase it another way: I want to assign `jmatrix` at the start of the code and later on, if `nmax` and `kmax` change, I can reference `jmatrix` without reassigning it with respect to the new values of `nmax` and `kmax`. I'm also not sure what the difference between a `Single` and a `Double` is, but that's a less important part.

I hope that makes sense, and thanks for any input!

Comment: Single and double are the size (precision) of the floating point value. (I don't know much about R, so I'll skip the hard part of the question.)

Comment: From what I've read, that size gives VB flexibility in terms of memory allocation? Reserving only as much memory as you need, by being more specific about the nature of the reserved space? Or am I way of?

Comment: Yes, VB only reserves the amount of memory required for (nmax+1) * (kmax+1) elements of the array, plus a little overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These statements do not assign any value to the objects but rather allocate space and type:

```
Dim ff(nmax) As Double
Dim jmatrix(nmax, kmax) As Double
```

The equivalents in R would be:

```
ff <- vector('numeric', length=nmax)  # or ff <- numeric(nmax)
jmatrix <- matrix(numeric(nmax*kmax), nmax, kmax)
```

There is really no equivalent of "single" in R. There is an "integer"-mode which uses 4 bytes per element and your code `0:nmax` would have created a specific integer sequence which is not what those Dim VB statements were doing. Your `as.numeric(.)`  would have then changed the class of that result to the R equivalent of "double".

R's objects may not hold their type if an assignment is made. Matrices need to be all of the same mode. You could assign a character value to a position in `jmatrix` and it would change the entire matrix to character mode.

I don't know the internals of VB or VBA and the R semantics will allocate space in for an object, but assignment to the object may still require copying the result to a *tmp* value and then assigning that result to a symbol. This means you may need three similar sized objects in the workspace at the same time before the original object's space and the *tmp*-space is released.

Lists are dynamic structures in the sense that assigning to a position that doesn't exist will automatically extend the object, but matrices are not so designed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this option is available in R, and you have to create a new "object" every time the parameter changes. One idea is to declare *jmatrix* as function and call it whenever you want to reference.

```
jmatrix <- function() return(matrix(nrow=nmax, ncol=kmax))
jmatrix()
```

Comment: That makes sense! You could then assign a vector based on its outputs, like so? `jmatrix_assign<-jmatrix()`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. But again, once the variable is assigned, it is not changed until you manually do so.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm mostly looking for a way around that. It sounds like that's just not how R works, though.

To clarify the above: if `jmatrix()` is defined as above, then each time you ran it you would return a matrix built of `nmax` and `kmax` as they are defined in the current environment. If `nmax` and `kmax` change, then so does your output from `jmatrix()`. I mentioned reassigning the outputs because its not immediately clear to me how to use a function like that in, say, a `for` loop.

Comment: Actually running `jmatrix()` would do essentially nothing except consume a few CPU cycles, since the value was not assigned to a symbol in the workspace. It would be wiped out in the next garbage collection.

Comment: I only suggested that the user uses `jmatrix()` instead of `jmatrix` to reference this "dynamic" variable. eg: `print( jmatrix() )`